# Finding arduous Functions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The problem is:

Find all functions $f(x,y)$ such that:

$f(x,y){(1 - 3x^2)} = {(x^3 + y^2)}{(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}} (x,y)) - {(x^2 + y)} {(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}} (x,y))$

I am not being able to think the first step to proceed with the problem. Please help me.

Comment: You ask to "Find a function" solution of the given equation. Are you sure that you want only a function ? If yes, $f(x,y)=0$ is what you want. Are you sure that the question is not "Find all the functions"?

Comment: @JJacquelin Oops...Yes it should be find all the functions...

Comment: @JJacquelin Any algorithm to find out a function with terms containing variables x or y or both will be helpful

Comment: Don't expect an algorithm, but a method to solve first order linear PDEs. You said "I am  not being able to think the first step to proceed". Thus, first you have to learn the "method of characteristics" for example : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics . Hang in there !

Comment: @JJacquelin Surely, I will go through the article...but if you find any other function other than 0, then let me know

Comment: @JJacquelin I am sad

Comment: @JJacquelin I am new here, I am not aware....

Comment: You could expect more answers if you re-edit your question with more information about the context : If the equation comes from  physics, use a numerical method to solve it. If it comes from an academic exercise, edit what you did to find the equation. In all cases, edit the original wording of the problem (not in comment, but in the question).

Comment: Solve the PDE $(1-3x^2)f = (x^3+y^2)f_x-(x^2+y)f_y$ using the characteristic method

Comment: @JJacquelin Okay, in future I won't post any such questions again

Comment: @Cesareo I am trying

Comment: @pan dong : You have to understand that we will not waste time to study an equation which might be not correct. May be there is a typo in it. May be the equation is false because you made a mistake is the calculus to derive the equation from the original wording of the problem. There might be other kind of mishmash. Before spending time, we want to be sure that  it is worthwhile. Even if you say "I am sure that the written equation is correct", this cannot be taken for granted.